# Обрезается текст на странице предложенных правок

Tags: дефект, дизайн

На странице [утвержденной правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/92186) вертикально обрезается текст справа:

[image: обрезан текст]

Вероятно, как-то связано с наклонным стилем шрифта.

Проявляется в браузерах FF (47.0.1) и Chrome (51.0.2704.106 m). В IE (11.0), на удивление, всё нормально. Хотя при выделении текста мышью наблюдается аналогичный эффект.

Актуально для номинального масштабирования страницы (т.е. 100%), в FF устанавливается через <kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd>. Скриншот на всякий случай:

[image: 100%]

Comment: У меня перенос после слова October, т.е. бага нет. FF 47.

Comment: @NickVolynkin покрутите масштабирование страницы через `Ctrl+колесо`. У меня только на одном (текущем) масштабе заметно.

Comment: на 40% и 50% воспроизводится. Неясно, должны ли разработчики сайта предусматривать такие ситуации.

Comment: @NickVolynkin моё дело - проинформировать :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у меня хром. Первая строка переносится после "October", но далее слово "стандартно" обрезается. Масштаб 100%.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то проблема в некорректном отображении текста при увеличении. За это отвечает обозреватель (браузер). Уверен, именно разработчики обозревателя отвечают за правильную работу алгоритмов увеличения/уменьшения при использовании разных языков и шрифтов.

Comment: Можно ли отображение на масштабе `100%` считать "увеличением"?

Comment: @alexolut Как я понимаю, что речь шла именно про измененный масштаб.

Comment: В моём случае - нет. И у @Qwertiy аналогично. Добавил про `100%` в вопрос.